# Saving Theme returns TImeout error in Drupal 6.16 after changing server

Tags: 6, migrations

Everything was working fine till I was on my old server. After migrating it to a new server with same configuration (better memory and added load balancer), when I try saving the theme from the theme page http://mysite.com/admin/build/themes, after waiting for some time I get a 504 Gateway Timeout error from nginx.

Hope I get some response here and the experts can help me resolve this question.

**EDIT**

I just noticed if I perform any postback operation that is related to Drupal core modules, the issue is present. I am able to add/edit/delete data and do postbacks on admin pages that are created via a custom module, but the page just does nto work when on Core Druapl admin pages -

1. Save Theme
2. Clear Cache
3. Add Node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue at my end was related to server configuration. Nginx server was timing out and the load balancer was not redirecting the urls properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you've allowed enough  time for script execution on your new server? Changing this to a higher value might help:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', YOURVALUE);
```

Changing theme settings and installing / uninstalling modules needs a longer execution than most other operations I would imagine.

Sorry if my suggestion was already obvious to you.

Comment: Yes, I have checked all I could do. No results. My Server admin says it has something to do with serializing in bootstrap.inc file..